# Why does Spanish have three different command forms (positive/negative tú, usted)

Tags: etimología, conjugación

Unlike English, Spanish seems to have have commands whose form depends on both the type (affirmative/negative) and also the person (*tú*, *usted*, *ustedes*).

While the construction of the affirmative *tú* command by using the third person form essentially mirrors its construction in English (Jump! --> *¡Salta!*), the negative form diverges from its English equivalent.

Whereas in English you would just add "Don't" to the beginning, in Spanish you change the conjugation by adding *es/as* to the end of the yo form.

So a few etymological questions:

1. Why did the difference between affirmative/negative commands arise?
2. Why does the negative command use the yo form as the prefix?
3. Why does the ending seem "switched" — that is, "-ar" verbs use the "es" ending whereas "-er/-ir" verbs use the "as" ending?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Depending on how one counts, Spanish has a great deal more than three forms for commands.

There are only three true *imperative* forms of each verb (I'll use the verbs *hablar*, *comer*, and *vivir* for my examples throughout this answer):

- **tú**: habla, come, vive
  <sup>(*tú* form less the *-s*; several irregulars: *di, haz, pon, sal, sé, ten, ve, ven*; *estar* always reflexive: *estate*)</sup>
- **vos**: hablá, comé, viví
  <sup>(*vos* form less the *-s*; one irregular: *ir* is *andá*)</sup>
- **vosotros**: hablad, comed, vivid
  <sup>(infinitive, less the *-r*, plus *-d* if non-reflexive; one irregular: *irse* is *idos*)</sup>

In older or very formal Spanish, the *vos* commands will be identical to the *vosotros* commands (they were derived from that form) and may retain the *-d-* in reflexive commands.

Before I get started on the rest, I'd just like to say don't oversimplify English commands.  They are actually a good bit more complicated than just adding "use the bare infinitive for affirmative, add *don't* to create a negative."  Many can take the word *not* after them to create the negative sans *do* ("fear not"); the first-person plural commands are formed with *let's* which creates an embedded clause ("let's play"); and when using *don't* or *do not* (for emphasis), you are actually switching to the emphatic mood which is also often used in affirmative commands ("do mind your manners").  And we don't even really have a way to give commands to people we aren't talking directly to, except by using a variety of structures using the modal verbs *let* ("let there be light") or *may* ("may they live happily ever after") which could be seen as either an impersonal command (*let*) or a fossilized subjunctive (*may*).  In any case, English commands are actually really quite complex when you think about it.

Back to Spanish.  Spanish could easily do third-person commands by using the subjunctive (nowadays, it's most common though not required to preface these with *que*; when used sans *que* it's called the *exhortative subjunctive*).  *Usted* back in the day wasn't a true pronoun, just a third-person honorific, so it was treated as any other third-person word.

For negative forms, Latin — out of which Spanish developed — didn't have a negative imperative: like English, it used a separate verb's command to form negative commands (*noli(te)* — from *nolo* — meaning "want not").  Spanish innovated a different form, using the subjunctive (perhaps derived from *(no quiero que) [verb]* or similar phrases).  This ended up being applied to all commands, first, second, or third person.

```
subject     affirmative                  negative (prefix all with "no")
---------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------
tú       |  habla     come     vive    |  *hables   *comas   *vivas
vos      |  hablá     comé     viví    | †*hablés  †*comás  †*vivás
usted    | *hable    *coma    *viva    |  *hable    *coma    *viva
nosotros | *hablemos *comamos *vivamos |  *hablemos *comamos *vivamos
vosotros |  hablad    comed    vivid   |  *habléis  *comáis  *viváis
ustedes  | *hablen   *coman   *vivan   |  *hablen   *coman   *vivan

* derived from subjunctive
† in Chile: *habléis, *comáis, *viváis with an optionally elided -s.
```

As to why the subjunctive form appears to be switched or is based off of the *yo* form verb, the reason is simply because that's how it was in Latin.  As to why Latin did it, generally when asking *why* in linguistics the answer is simply "because that's what people said".

Comment: Wow! If I had enough reputation to provide a bounty, I would; in its absence, I will have to make do with a hearty thank you!