# Are there verbs in Spanish meaning "to use the familiar/formal you" (like "to be on first-name terms" or "du sagen" in German)?

Tags: verbos, formalidad

In Spanish you have 2 forms of *you*:

- *tú* for familiar addressing (friends/peers)
- *Usted* for formal addressing

Is there a single verb meaning "to use *tú* to address him", something like the German *du sagen* or the English phrase *to be on first-name terms*? And analogically for "to use *Usted*"?

Comment: Check this out http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/7/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-t%c3%ba-usted-y-vos (sorry is in Spanish)

Comment: Ah... but this is in English. http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/15524/why-does-spanish-have-three-different-command-forms-positive-negative-t%c3%ba-usted so your question may be duplicate.

Comment: Spanish has three, actually. **tú** (*tutear*: use the tú form), **vos** (*vosear*: use the vos form) and **usted** (*tratar de usted*: use the usted form).

Comment: @guifa in Argentina we use *tutear* to talk about informal treatment, even when we use *vos*.

Comment: @rsanchez very true, its not universally used. Perhaos it's used more in places with a three way distinction. (I just haven't spent much time in voseo regions — two or three way distinctions)

Comment: @HonzaZidek it has three words for you (tú, vos, usted), and two words for y'all (vosotros, ustedes). Vos is singular and not always directly equivalent to tú, though it generally is — there are regions where vos is informal, usted is formal, and tú is intermediate.

Comment: @guifa: I confused *vos* with *vosotros*, sorry. I do not know *vos*, it was not in my Spanish textbook :)

Comment: that's actually the #1 complaint I have whenever I review textbooks - they don't mention *vos* even though it's very common (perhaps as 40% of speakers use it)

Comment: Side note: German has the compact verbs 'duzen' and 'siezen', for addressing someone with du/Sie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Tutear* may be what you are looking for, here.

[RAE entry](http://dle.rae.es/?id=azNQE9X)

> 1. tr. Dirigirse a alguien empleando el pronombre de segunda persona para el trato de confianza o familiaridad. U. t. c. prnl.

Translation:

> To address someone using the second person pronoun for trust and familiarity treatment

I can't recall any verb like this for *usted*, though. We use the phrase "tratar de usted".

Comment: What about the word *ustedear* as suggested by Rodrigo? However SpanishDict does not recognize ustedear. Also other native Spanish people here seem not to remember such a word. Is it only regional?

Comment: As a peninsular native, I have never heard of that word. Using _usted_ is the default when meeting someone for the first time -unless it's in an informal setting or between young people, like students, as peers- so it's not usually necessary. Maybe it's regional. When you want someone to treat you of _usted_ you simply ask them to stop using _tú_ or deny them the change of treatment if they get too confortable and ask you if they can use it. After a quick search most _ustedear_ and _ustedeo_ entries are related to Latin America.

Answer (score 2):

There is a verb for the informal case: *tutear*.

There is no single verb for the formal case, a common expression used is: *tratarse de usted*

See also [this question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2121/how-do-i-ask-someone-not-to-call-me-usted)

Answer (score 1):

> [Tutear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=azNQE9X) (familiar adressing).
>
> [Ustedear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bBiV3Vo) (formal addresing).

Comment: SpanishDict recognize tutear - http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/tutear, however it does not recognize ustedear. Also other native Spanish people here seem not to remember such a word. Is it only regional?

Comment: Is in the RAE, see the link. Not a word much used, but is available.

Comment: WHERE is it used? Is it regional somewhere in Latin America?

Comment: @Honza Zidek: What a strange question. It is a word _of the Spanish language_, is not used in any particular region. It is part of the huge number of words you'll hear in your life rarely or never, as posma, ahíto, ablución, obnubilado... I used it years ago in my student days because voseo/ tuteo/ustedeo is very important in the study of grammar, but do not think it's a technicality, it's just a word that is rarely used.

Comment: I asked RAE.

From: consu2 <consu2@rae.es>
Date: 2016-03-18 14:49 GMT+01:00
 
En efecto, uste(d)ear y uste(d)eo son recientes incorporaciones al diccionario académico, y podemos decirle que su empleo no está generalizado en español. De hecho, el Diccionario del español actual de M. Seco las marca como raras. Aunque su formación es correcta y las formas análogas tutear y tuteo están plenamente asentadas en el uso, lo cierto es que es mucho más común para este caso el empleo de una expresión pluriverbal: tratar/tratamiento de usted.

Departamento de «Español al día»
Real Academia Española

Comment: And I do not think it's a strange question! Some words are *rare known* (everybody knows but usually does not use), some are *rare unknown* (only people belonging to certain social group know them) and some are *regional* (people is some places even never heard of, whilst for other places it is very common). Which category do you think the word *ustedear* belong to?