# ¿Por qué no se puede usar el imperativo en negativo?

Tags: verbos, historia, imperativo

Hoy en el trabajo alguien ha puesto en el chat interno:

> No desplegad nada hasta nuevo aviso.

Automáticamente pensé que la frase estaba mal redactada, tal vez por un exceso de corrección, y que tendría que haber puesto "no despleguéis", haciendo uso del presente de subjuntivo para indicar una orden en negativo. Pero ¿por qué?

El imperativo es el único tiempo (¿modo?) verbal que exige que las frases se redacten en afirmativo, pasando a usarse el presente de subjuntivo en caso contrario: *canta* versus *no cantes*, *comed* frente a *no comáis*.

La cuestión es ¿por qué esto es así? ¿Ha sido por la evolución histórica del modo imperativo? ¿Qué origen tiene como para que no admita su uso en negativo, como en el ejemplo al principio de la pregunta? ¿O es sencillamente por evitar confusiones con otros tiempos? ¿Existió algún momento de la historia del idioma en el que fuese común el uso de *no cantad* antes que *no cantéis*?

Comment: La última sección de esta respuesta aborda esta pregunta brevemente: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/15524/why-does-spanish-have-three-different-command-forms-positive-negative-t%c3%ba-usted/15527#15527

Comment: @ukemi «... generally when asking why in linguistics the answer is simply "because that's what people said".» Great. :-D

Comment: Este artículo presenta una teoría morfológica que admite la gramaticalidad de los imperativos negativos no-subjuntivos en el caso de *vosotros* (como se muestra en el mensaje de tu colega): http://www.lingref.com/cpp/hls/15/paper2892.pdf

Comment: @ukemi interesante, curioso que mencione que puede ser una forma de hipercorrección, tal y como yo pensaba.

Comment: Es porque en latín el imperativo negativo se hacía mediante un verbo que, en positivo, era conceptualmente negativo (tipo, ignorar en afirmativo = saber en negativo). El verbo usaod significaba *no querer*, equivalente (pero en afirmativo!) al castellano *no queráis hacer algo* por *no hagáis algo*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He encontrado información al respecto en la [*Enciclopedia dell'Italiano* Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/imperativo_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/), ya que compara cómo han evolucionado a partir del latín diferentes lenguas románicas en relación a la manera de expresar el imperativo negativo.

Según esta fuente, en el latín clásico existían cuatro maneras diferentes de construir un imperativo negativo:

> - la negación *ne* + el presente del subjuntivo (*ne ames*, *ne timeatis*);
> - la negación *ne* + el imperativo futuro (*ne amato*, *ne amatone*);
> - el imperativo *noli* o *nolite* (imperativos de *nolo* «no querer») + infinitivo (*noli amare*, *nolite amare*);
> - la negación *ne* + el perfecto del subjuntivo (o futuro anterior), para expresar una prohibición categórica (*ne amaveris*).

Y, a continuación, se explica:

> Se il francese moderno, innovando, esprime l’imperativo negativo con la semplice negazione della forma positiva (*chante* → *ne chante pas*; *prends* → *ne prends pas*); se lo spagnolo e il portoghese continuano la prima possibilità del latino (spagn. *no cantes*, *no cantéis*, *no vendas*, *no vendáis*; port. *não cantes*, *não canteis*, *não vendas*, *não vendais*), l’italiano – come anche il romeno e il francese antico – nell’adoperare la costruzione *non* + infinito per la II persona sing., opera una sorta di fusione tra la terza e la quarta possibilità del latino.

Mi traducción:

> Si el francés moderno, innovando, expresa el imperativo negativo simplemente con la negación de la forma positiva (*chante* → *ne chante pas*; *prends* → *ne prends pas*); si el español y el portugués se quedan con la primera posibilidad del latín (español *no cantes*, *no cantéis*, *no vendas*, *no vendáis*; portugués *não cantes*, *não canteis*, *não vendas*, *não vendais*), el italiano – como también el rumano y el francés antiguo – utilizando la construcción *non* + infinitivo para la segunda persona singular, adopta una especie de fusión entre  la tercera y la cuarta posibilidad del latín.

En resumen, de las cuatro maneras que tenía el latín para expresar un imperativo negativo listadas más arriba, la lengua española adopta la primera, la partícula de negación  ("no") + el presente del subjuntivo.